# WPF - Change the color of an entire textblock line

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF Application I have a two textblocks which get filled from the code behind with a run. Every second line should have a different background color so it gets easier to read. Unfortunately, the lines are only dyed as far as they are written. But I want the background color to go over the entire line and not just the written area.

Code:

```
         for (int i = 0; i < GlobalSettings.prefixList.Count; i++)
         {
            runLeft = new Run(GlobalSettings.prefixList[i].prefix + "\n");
            runRight = new Run(GlobalSettings.prefixList[i].amount + "\n");
            
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                runLeft.Background = Brushes.Gray;
                runRight.Background = Brushes.Gray;
            }
            else
            {
                runLeft.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                runRight.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            }

            tblock_StatisticsLeft.Inlines.Add(runLeft);
            tblock_StatisticsRight.Inlines.Add(runRight);
         }
```

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmx6G.png)

The two textblocks are seamlessly together in the middle so it would look like it is a single line in a single textblock. The spaces between the lines are negligible if this makes it easier.

Is there a solution without using a textbox or richtextbox?

**EDIT:**

XAML Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MuseKeyGenApp.UCStartUp"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MuseKeyGenApp"
         mc:Ignorable="d"   
         Background = "#FF0069B4"
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*" MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*" MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*" MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*" MinWidth="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,35,12,12" Name="sv_PrefixList">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tblock_StatisticsLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LineHeight="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tblock_StatisticsRight" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LineHeight="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

I left out all the other stuff of the control that is not relevant.

Comment: Why don't you set the Background property of the tblock_StatisticsLeft and tblock_StatisticsRight TextBlocks instead of setting the Background property of the Run elements?

Comment: Because the whole textblock would have a single color and not for every single line a seperate color as  I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What's behind the TextBlocks then? What kind of ItemsControl are you using? You need to set the background property of the element that is seen behind the TextBlocks.

Comment: There is nothing behind. XAML Code:  <TextBlock   x:Name="tblock_StatisticsLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LineHeight="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="TextBlock" TextAlignment="Left"/>

Comment: Of course there is *something* behind a TextBlock. Please post the entire XAML markup of your window along with your code.

Comment: You should use an ItemsControl. Please see my answer.

Comment: Put it in a Border and change the color of the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (should) use an `ItemsControl`. Set the `ItemsSource` property of it to your `GlobalSettings.prefixList` collection, i.e. you replace your for loop with this:

```
ic.ItemsSource = GlobalSettings.prefixList;
```

Make sure that "prefix" and "amount" are public *properties* (and not fields) of your "prefix" type or whatever you call it:

```
public string prefix { get; set; }
```

You then put the `Grid` with the TextBlocks in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ItemsControl` and bind the TextBlocks to the "prefix" and "amount" properties:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,35,12,12" Name="sv_PrefixList">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ic" AlternationCount="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tblock_StatisticsLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LineHeight="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left"
                                       Text="{Binding prefix}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tblock_StatisticsRight" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LineHeight="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right"
                                       Text="{Binding amount}"/>
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" TargetName="grid"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" TargetName="grid"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This should get you coloured lines.

Comment: I'll tested it and it works perfect! Do you know why they have to be public properties and can't just be fields?

Comment: Didn't know about _ItemsControl.AlternationIndex_. Thanks.

Comment: @Gistiv: Because you can only bind to public properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way of doing this:

Xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:BackConverter x:Key="BackConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10">
    <ItemsControl Name="ic"> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
               <DockPanel.Background>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BackConverter}">
                                <Binding />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DockPanel.Background>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Left}">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Right}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

c# code:

```
  public class obj
    {
        public string Left { get; set; }
        public string Right { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        List<obj> objects = new List<obj>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var left = "aaaaa";
            var right = "bbbbb";
            objects.Add(new obj() { Left = left, Right = right }); 
        }
        ic.ItemsSource = objects;

    }
```

the converter:

```
public class BackConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var index = ((ItemsControl)values[1]).Items.IndexOf(values[0]);
        if (index % 2 == 0)
            return Brushes.Gray;
        return Brushes.White; 
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efford. I tried it but it didn't give me the result i wanted. The color is still just dyed where text is and i want to have to entire line dyed.

Comment: you are right. it fixes easily: set the background part as the background of the stackpanel.